# SYSVOL not replicating to some RODC

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, synchronization, rodc, sysvol

I'm stumped.

I was trying to replicate a file (corporate wallpaper) to branch offices via SYSVOL (so that workstations in branch offices don't have to pull the file from HO). However, the replication only worked for some RODCs, but failed on other RODCs.

On one failed RODC, I tried forcing replication by using the command `ntfrsutl.exe forcerepl DEST_RODC_NAME /r "Domain System Volume (SYSVOL share)" /p dc01.example.com` ... and within minutes, the wallpaper appeared!

What could possibly the problem here? Why won't some RODC perform automatic sync?

Comment: How long did you wait? What's your sites and services configuration replication between sites? Things like this are configurable and by default are usually 15 minutes.

Comment: 4 hours. Which should be long enough, no?

Comment: I recently became aware of the FRS becoming deprecated in the 2008/2008R2 world, maybe converting to DFS for sysvol replication will fix your problem: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd640019(v=ws.10).aspx though, I'd still like to know why your current setup is broke.

Comment: @SpacemanSpiff sorry for not replying sooner. I left my office in disgust (with my smartphone busily googling for answers)... the next morning, all RODC had replicated! o_O ... now what I need to do is to find out why it takes >5 hours to replicate -_-

Comment: Check out that link, it appears there are tools you can use for validation of health along the way, even if you don't go through with the conversion.

Comment: Okay, thanks. Can you kind of 'summarize' your comments above into an answer? I'll checkmark it ASAP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look into converting from FRS to DFS-R replication. Along the way you'll probably figure out what's going on and why things are taking so long, and move away from the now deprecated FRS sysvol replication.

Here's the article from Microsoft outlining the process: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd640019(v=ws.10).aspx

In particular you can take note of the health checks at the beginning. This might also be a good time to repadmin and be sure that AD itself is resolving all SRV records properly and replicating as it should.